# logarithmic rules with functions

Tags: logarithms

Do the logarithmic rules work when taking logs of functions as opposed to numbers?

i.e. suppose $f$ is a function and $n$ is a real number, is $\log (f(x)^n) = n · \log(f(x))$?

Comment: Of course, because the equality is true for any specific $x$.

Comment: @Mark : What you have said is meaningless. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why is it meaningless? Put any constant $x$ and you will get an equality. Two functions are equal if they are equal at all points.

Comment: Okay, I guess I understand what you mean. Note that, unfortunately, OP has omitted any mention of $x$ on the RHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will work.

$$\log(f(x)^n) = \log(f(x)\times f(x) ... \times f(x)$$
$$= \log(f(x)) +\log(f(x)) + ... +\log(f(x))$$
$$=n \times \log(f(x))$$

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for $f(x) > 0$? Especially if $n$ is even. Suppose $f(x)=-2$, then $f(x)^n>0$, so $\log(f(x)^n)$ is defined, but $\log(f(x))$ isn't.

Comment: @JAD `log(-1) = π * i` - i.e. log of a negative real number is a complex number, so answer is NO - it will perfectly work on negative values, except that number domain changes. And besides this isn't related to a f(x), but to log() domain in general.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas alright, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course.

Because $f(x)$ is still a number for any $x$.

It even works on expressions: for example $\log((x^2+3)^9)=9\log(x^2+3).$